# MongoDB project all values except one in embedded fields

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of `players` with documents like this:

```
{
  id: 123,
  country: 'GB',
  names: { 
    key1: 'John Paul', 
    key2: 'Johny Paul',
    key3: 'Johny-paul',
    key4: 'Johny-paul'
  } 
},
{
  id: 1234,
  country: 'GB',
  names: { 
    key1: 'Mike Pitt',     
    key3: 'Mike-Pitt'    
  } 
}
```

Then I want to **project only all values of** `names` except `key2`:

```
{
  names: { 
    key1: 'John Paul', 
    key3: 'Johny-paul',
    key4: 'Johny-paul'
  } 
},
{
  names: { 
    key1: 'Mike Pitt',     
    key3: 'Mike-Pitt'    
  } 
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
db.collection('players').find({}).project({ 'names.key2': 0, 'names': 1 })
```

But I get this error:

```
MongoError: Projection cannot have a mix of inclusion and exclusion.
```

Something like this does not help me because the field `names` **may grow in the future with new keys**:

```
db.collection('players').find({}).project({ 'names.key1': 1, 'names.key2': 0, 'names.key3': 1, 'names.key4': 1 })
```

Also tried something with ES6 this but is much more expensive:

```
(db.collection('players').find({}).project({ 'names.key2': 0}).toArray()).map(p => p.names);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple aggregation pipeline with a `$unset` and `$project` stages, which will project the items.

```js
db.players.aggregate([
    { $unset: "names.key2" },
    { $project: { _id :0, "names" : 1 } }
]).pretty()

{ "names" : {
        "key1" : "John Paul",
        "key3" : "Johny-paul",
        "key4" : "Johny-paul"
    }
}
{ "names" : {
        "key1" : "Mike Pitt",
        "key3" : "Mike-Pitt"
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to project only **all values of names** except key2, you are projecting **all values** except key2

Comment: @kurtko Sorry, I must have read your question incorrectly, I've updated the answer with a correct solution.